# php function like wordpress the_content()

Tags: php

aIs there a function in php (like Wordpress's the_content()) that can limit a text string without breaking the html tags that may be within it?

```
//example:
echo substr ('<p>this <a>is</a> a test</p>', 0, 10);

//output: "<p>this <a"
//desired output: "<p>this </p>"
```

Comment: The proper approach is generally to normalize the content so that there is no markup, and then add it after the fact for specific purposes...

Comment: Its included in wp-includes/post-template.php if you want to have a look at how it works.

Comment: http://core.svn.wordpress.org/branches/3.4/wp-includes/post-template.php Search for `function get_the_content` to see how they do it.

Comment: @prodigitalson I think you are right, I think this is the way to go. Combining your method with a function like substr() that will limit a string but only at the next white space, so you don't end up with regex wraping urls that have been cut in half.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not.  But you could dig into Wordpress's source and see what `the_content()` does to achieve that.  I haven't done so myself.  Preserving HTML tags in the shorter version will be a tricky block of code.

What do you need this for?  Are you just trying to obtain a preview of a longer HTML blob?  In the past I've done this by using a combination of `strip_tags()` and `substr()`, and wrapping the stripped section of content in a new `<p>` tag.